# Error: Can't find stylesheet to import when trying to import scss file in Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I keep receiving this error:

```
/* Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
 *   ,
 * 1 | @import "../stylesheets/mediaqueries";
 *   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 *   '
 *   page-not-found.component.scss 1:9  root stylesheet */
```

when trying to import an external SCSS file into a component's SCSS file. The SCSS file I'm trying to import contains mixins and media queries I want to use on the component. The path to the SCSS file I'm trying to import is `./src/stylesheets/scss-file`

The path to my component's SCSS file is `./src/app/components/component/component-scss-file`

I'm not sure why I keep receiving this error when trying to import the scss file containing the mixins. How can I resolve this issue?

Contents of mixin SCSS file:

```
$querystring: "only screen and (min-width: ";

$tablet-size: 768px;
$laptop-size: 1024px;
$large-laptop-size: 1440px;
$desktop-size: 1920px;
$fourk-size: 2560px;

$mobile-device: #{$querystring} + "(max-width: " + $tablet-size +")";
$tablet: #{$querystring} + $tablet-size +")";
$laptop: #{$querystring} + $laptop-size +")";
$laptop-large: #{$querystring} + $laptop-size +")";
$desktop: #{$querystring} + $desktop-size +")";
$fourk: #{$querystring} + $fourk-size +")";

@mixin mobile-devices {
  @media #{$mobile-device} {
    @content
  }
}

@mixin tablets {
  @media #{$tablet} {
    @content
  }
}

@mixin laptops {
  @media #{$laptop} {
    @content
  }
}

@mixin laptops-large {
  @media #{$laptop-large} {
    @content
  }
}

@mixin desktops {
  @media #{$desktop} {
    @content
  }
}

@mixin fourk {
  @media #{$fourk} {
    @content
  }
}
```

Import that gives error:

```
@import "../stylesheets/scss-file";
```

angular.json file:

```
...
"assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./src/stylesheets"
              ]
            },
...
```

Comment: Why are you adding it to pre-processor path if you are importing it else where

Comment: I added it there after getting the error, thought adding it to pre-processor would fix it but it didn't fix the erorr

Comment: If the file paths that you provided are true then your import path is wrong
it should be ../../../style-sheets/mediaqueries

You need to go three steps back in path and in actual you are only going only step back

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked. Is there any way to replace the ../../../? because that is ugly and difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

If using a JetBrains IDE and their SASS/SCSS/ file watcher with an Angular project, the file watcher is not aware of the `angular.json` file and therefore an error will always post in the run dialog box. However, I noticed when previewing the effected page in the browser, the styling is applied nonetheless. Hopefully JetBrains can come up with a way for the file watcher to be made aware of the `angular.json` file in a future update.